# How to concatenate multiple variables?

Tags: python, raspbian

I have three UV sensors - integers output; one BME280 - float output (temperature and pressure); and one GPS Module - float output.
I need to build a string in this form - **#teamname;temperature;pressure;uv_1;uv_2;uv_3;gpscoordinates#**

and send them via ser.write at least one time per second- I'm using APC220 Module

Is this the right (and fastest) way to do it?

```
textstr = str("#" + "teamname" + ";" + str(temperature) + ";" + str(pressure) + ";" + str(uv_1) + ";" + str(uv_2) + ";" + str(uv_3) + "#")

(...)

ser.write(('%s \n'%(textstr)).encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: why the outer call to `str`? it is pointless.

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like this:

```
vars = [teamname, temperature, pressure, uv_1, uv_2, uv_3, gpscoordinates]
joined = ';'.join( map( str, vars ))
ser.write( '#%s# \n', joined )
```

Answer (score 3):

If using `python 3.6+` then you can do this instead

```py
textstr = f"#teamname;{temperature};{pressure};{uv_1};{uv_2};{uv_3}# \n"

(...)

ser.write((textstr).encode('utf-8'))
```

If `teamname` and `gpscoordinates` are also variables then add them the same way

```py
textstr = f"#{teamname};{temperature};{pressure};{uv_1};{uv_2};{uv_3};{gpscoordinates}# \n"

(...)

ser.write((textstr).encode('utf-8'))
```

For more info about string formatting
https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 1):

It might improve readability to use python's `format`:

```
textstr = "#teamname;{};{};{};{};gpscoordinates#".format(temperature, pressure, uv_1, uv_2, uv_3)
ser.write(('%s \n'%(textstr)).encode('utf-8'))
```

assuming `gpscoordinates` is text (it's not in your attempted code). If it's a variable, then replace the text with `{}` and add it as a param to `format`.